# Gnuplot Cumulative Column Question

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have some data.

```
#Time  Distance
 1   3
 2   5
 4   9
 8  11
12  17
14  20
16  34
20  40
```

I want to plot the cumulative distance wrt time in gnuplot ... (it should be easy) but I do not know how.

x

Comment: Hmm ... the columns were HTMLized away ... okay ... please take each row pair as pair of columns ...

x

Comment: Okay someone fixed it ... aah the joy of being an SO noob.

Comment: @Xofo, just add 4 spaces before each line and the characters are even spaced. There are more solutions, but this works ;-). And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 28):

For anyone still looking for this sort of thing, If your gnuplot version is 4.4 or newer, you can do the following:

```
a=0
#gnuplot 4.4+ functions are now defined as:  
#func(variable1,variable2...)=(statement1,statement2,...,return value)
cumulative_sum(x)=(a=a+x,a)
plot "test.dat" using 1:(cumulative_sum($2))
```

Comment: I'm running gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 2, your script results in an `undefined variable: a` error for me.

Comment: @Thomas -- Are you sure you remembered the `a=0` at the top?

Comment: Oops, I can't believe I didn't see that. It works alright. Thanks, mate, now I feel stupid. :-)

Comment: Hmm...This might be my best chance for a Necromancer badge so far!  :-)

Comment: This does not work if you want to plot multiple comulative datasets at once. Also, you need to reset a to zero after every run (if you are using the interactive gnuplot prompt, at least). For me, the `smooth cumulative` solution worked better.

Comment: This is a nice solution because it can be generalized. Sometimes you need to have the tail distribution. Now it is easy using something along these lines `a=max; tailDF(x)=(a=a-x,a)`. I can't see how the same could be achieved using, say, `smooth cumulative`.

Answer (score 16):

If your data is in the file datafile, you can do a cumulative plot like so:

```
$ gnuplot
gnuplot> plot "datafile" smooth cumulative
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your data is in a file "test.txt", how about:

```
plot "<awk '{i=i+$2; print $1,i}' test.txt" with lines
```

Comment: I found that THIS does not work cleanly if you have FLOATING POINT PAIRS. The error I got was:

awk: (FILENAME=out.txt FNR=131) fatal: print to "standard output" failed (Broken pipe)
              ^
         Bad data on line 1

---

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it with floats and it worked for me.  What's on your line 1?  Is it the header?  Try maybe removing that.

Answer (score 6):

The same can be achieved by the "cumulative" variant of the "smooth" option (just enter `help smooth` in gnuplot).

Answer (score 5):

This isn't what the question is looking for but "gnuplot cumulative distribution function" always leads me here and none of the answers are quite right unless you already have the data gnuplot expects.

But suppose you wanted a cumulative distribution function of *just* distances and only have the raw distances. There is a little trick with which gnuplot can calculate the `y` values:

`test.dat`:

```
#Time  Distance
 1   3
 2   5
 4   9
 8  11
12  17
14  20
16  34
20  40
```

`plot.gpi`:

```
datafile = test.dat
stats datafile
plot datafile using 2:(1./STATS_records) smooth cumulative title "distance"
```

[image]

It is not as flexible as having all the data, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little experience with Gnuplot and I just pored over the documentation some. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a solution for generating a cumulative sum as you're plotting.

I think what you'll need to do is to massage your data with another program before letting Gnuplot at it. [awk](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/gawk.html) is one program that comes to mind, it's practically built for fiddling with columnar data. You can integrate this process into the plotting process by following [these instructions](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00082000000000000000).

Comment: @Carl, sorry I inadvertently implemented your answer!  I wish SO was a little faster with those "New Answer Posted" messages.

Comment: Don't be sorry, I'm flattered that my suggestion is what worked for you! Happy hacking.