# Plotting x versus sum(y)

Tags: gnuplot

Consider data set of the following form:

```
1   3
1   10
2   7
2   14
3   9
```

I want a gnuplot script that plot only 3 points (1, 3+10), (2, 7+14), (3, 9)? The question is in a similar flavor to [Gnuplot Cumulative Column Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730913/gnuplot-cumulative-column-question), but that doesn't really solve my particular problem.

Comment: Are the empty lines intentional? If not, you should remove them from your sample data.

Comment: @Marcus: I removed empty lines.

Comment: After your confirmation I reformatted your question to use a different way of highlighting the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the link that you mentioned gives you a good hint: you can use AWK to pre-process your data and then pipe it into gnuplot.

The following line should give you what you need (assuming your data is in file `in.txt`):

```
plot "<awk '{ if ($1 == last_x) sum_y += $2 ; else { print last_x, sum_y; sum_y = $2 } last_x=$1} END { print last_x, sum_y }' in.txt" with lines
```

Of course, the inlining renders the AWK script unreadable, so I repeat it here for clarity:

```
{
    if ($1 == last_x)
        sum_y += $2
    else {
        print last_x, sum_y
        sum_y = $2
    }
    last_x=$1
}
END { 
    print last_x, sum_y        
}
```

**ADDENDUM**

If case your input file is not sorted according to the X coordinate you can enhance the pipe to include a call to `sort`:

```
plot "< sort -n -k 1 in.txt | awk '{ if ($1 == last_x) sum_y += $2 ; else { print last_x, sum_y; sum_y = $2 } last_x=$1} END { print last_x, sum_y }'" with lines
```

Comment: Thank you this works! However, it only works when all the same x-values are consecutive. I presume there must be a complicated way of achieving it for general case too.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot has a few smoothing options. One of those is `smooth frequency` what does exactly what you want:

```
plot 'data.txt' smooth frequency w l
```

It first renders the data monotonic in x, and then sums up all y-values for the same x-values.