# gnuplot "condition" : multiples curves (30 ?) on three columns

Tags: python, gnuplot

I've written few scripts in my life, but I almost only do bash. Never needed more. Until now : I want to make some graph from a wrapper, with these

```
1 type1 1
2 type1 2
3 type2 1
4 type1 3
5 type2 2
6 type3 1
```

Where the pattern is :

- 1st column : Rank {1..10000}
- 2nd column : Category (known)
- 3rd column : is compting how many time it saw the Category data in % of the total (range 0 to 1), from the beginning (I don't have the word in english ? `cumulate sum` maybe ?

in spreadsheet, the 3d column would be something like `=(NB.si($B$1:$B4;$B4)/nb.si($B$1:$B;$B4)` for the 4th row.

---

I'm still processing how I will, in python, append that "cumulate" sum in the data (I only have the two first column at the time), it's simple math and text processing scripting. I know how to do automate it in spreadsheets, have some idea in bash, but I know too little of python. But there, it's not my question (but I'm opened to benevolent people here :) )

---

## Question

I found `gnuplot` might help, and I read the manual and few samples on various websites, but I'm still little confused : how would I plot tree curves, starting from 0, going to 1, with

- X axe : Column 1
- Y axe : Column 3
- Curve : {type1, type2, type3}

[image: sample]

---

Thanks guys ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
# this function relates every type to an int, convenient for setting the plot styles
f(x) = x eq "type1"? 1: x eq "type2"? 2:0

# this tell gnuplot to ignore the result of lines not matching
set datafile missing "NaN"

# setting a nice style for every type
set style line 1 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "red"
set style line 2 linetype 1 linewidth 2 pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "blue"

# using a ternary operator to pick out the lines matching that type
plot for [i in "type1 type2"] 'test.dat' u (strcol(2) eq i?$3:NaN) w l ls f(i)
```

And get this
[image: Result]

If you want you can remove the `for` from the plot command and use just `plot 'test.dat' u (strcol(2) eq "type1"?$3:NaN) w l ls 1, 'test.dat' u (strcol(2) eq "type2"?$3:NaN) w l ls 2`, plotting explicitly for every type and have grater control over the details of each plotted line.

You can make another function to add the title for every line, similar to `f(x)` but returning the string for each type rather than an int.

I have also heard of ways of doing the cumulative sum inside gnuplot with awk or an internal function, you can check that out here [gnuplot-cumulative-column-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730913/gnuplot-cumulative-column-question)